# Present habits: would?

Tags: would

> Writing a novel is like telling a big, exciting story with lots of
> words. First, authors come up with cool ideas for characters and
> adventures. They use their imagination to create a beginning, middle,
> and end for the story. Then, they write every day, adding more and
> more to their book until it is finished. After writing, they (19) --
> it again, fix mistakes, and make the story even better before sharing
> it with others. Writing a novel takes time and lots of creativity, but
> it is a fun way to share amazing tales with the world.
>
> A) had to read
>
> C) used to read
>
> B) may have read
>
> D) would read
>
> E) might read

According to the answer key, the correct answer to the question is "E) might read". However, I think that "would read" can also be a correct choice. What do you think, can we use "would" to express present habits?

Comment: "would read" isn't right at all. The paragraph is mostly written in the present tense, so it would make no sense here. If there was an option for the future simple "will read", or just the present simple "read", these would be possible, but there are no such options.  Therefore, the only correct option is E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that both could make grammatical sense within the sentence in isolation, but 'might' and 'would' have different meanings so it would depend on what you want to say. Guessing which should go into somebody else's text involves knowing what *they* intend to say, so you need to rely on the wider context.

This text talks about the creative process of writing a novel, using the experience of actual authors. Saying that they *might* read it again, fix mistakes etc would imply that they *sometimes* do that, but not always. Saying they *would* do it suggests they always did it as part of the process and, *logically*, I would rule that out because every author works differently and there is no strict process that every author follows. But, further to that logic, the wider context also uses the present tense which means that certainty would be indicated with 'will', not 'would'. So you can be confident that 'might' is the correct answer.

Comment: Also, as the rest of the passage is in the present tense, _will read_ would fit better than _would read_.